Maximize the strength of a beam
I have a similar question from here, however, my rectangular beam is cut from a cylindrical torus with elliptical sections such that the major axis is 24cm and the minor axis, 16cm.
To find the value of the width $x$ and depth $y$, I maximized the strengh $S$: $S=8xy^2$, subject to $\frac{x^2}{144}+\frac{y^2}{64}=1$,
and the values I found were: $x=4\sqrt{3}$ and $y=8\sqrt{2/3}$. However, in the book, the answers are $x=4/\sqrt{3}$ and $y=4$.
What could be wrong?

Please [edit] your post to state the problem in a self-contained way, so we don't need to follow a link to understand what question you are asking or what the notation represents.  What do you mean by "the book"?  Please provide attribution to the source where you encountered this problem.

I think you made an arithmetic error somewhere.
The equation
$$\frac{x^2}{144}+\frac{y^2}{64}=1$$ is equivalent here to
$$y^2 = 64 - \frac{4x^2}{9}.$$
Plugging this into the equation gives $S$ as a function of $x$:
$$S= 8x\Big(64 - \frac{4x^2}{9}\Big) = 512x - \frac{32x^3}{9}.$$
Seeing what $dS/dx$ is, gives $$dS/dx = 512 - \frac{3 \cdot 32 x^2}{9}$$
$$= 512 -\frac{32x^2}{3},$$ and thus setting $dS/dx = 0$ yields
$$ \frac{dS}{dx} = 0 \implies 512 - \frac{32x^2}{3}=0$$ $$\implies 512  = \frac{32x^2}{3} \implies \frac{3 \cdot 512}{32} = x^2$$
$$\implies 4 \sqrt{3} = x.$$

Random comment:
The simplest checkup you could do is substitute the book values into the restrictions. For $x=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $y=4$, one gets:
$$
\dfrac{\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}{144}+\dfrac{4^2}{64} = \dfrac{1}{27} + \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{31}{108} \neq 1
$$

General solution:
Whilst Mike’s solution is perfectly fine, I’m going to spill down a general solution for this kind of problems, which could be easily extended to the case of multiple variables - more than just $(x,y)$ - and multiple non-trivial restrictions.
First of all, you need to construct a Lagrangian of a system subjected to aforementioned restrictions:
$$
\mathcal{L} = 8xy^2-\lambda\left(\frac{x^2}{144}+\frac{y^2}{64}-1\right)
$$
In general case, that would include as many $\lambda_i$ terms, as many restrictions you have.
To solve for the critical points, one must equate all the partial derivatives of this function (including derivatives over $\lambda_i$) to zero:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} 
&=& 8y^2 - \frac{\lambda x}{72} = 0 \\
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} 
&=& 16xy - \frac{\lambda y}{32} = 0 \\
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} &=& \dfrac{x^2}{144}+\dfrac{y^2}{64}-1 = 0
\end{array}
$$
From here, you would need to solve the system and find the critical points to investigate for extreme values.
Now, multiplying the first equation by $\frac{y}{4}$ and subtracting the second one multiplied by $\frac{x}{9}$ (to cancel out terms with $\lambda$), you’d obtain:
$$
2y^3-\frac{16}{9}x^2y = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2y(y^2-\frac{8}{9}x^2)=0
$$
Obviously, $y=0$ would be a bad solution to maximise the function $S$, so we won’t check it. On the other hand, what’s left in parentheses seems rather plausible. When you plug it into the last equation of the Lagrange system, you get $x=4\sqrt{3}$, $y=8\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.
Now, usually, you would have multiple tuples of solutions and you would need to check if what you've received is indeed an extremum. To do so, you would need to construct a Hessian of the Lagrange function $\mathcal{L}$ and check if the matrix is positive definite or negative definite at the critical points.
